# Raising an import error while trying to use flask _debugtoolbar

Tags: python, flask, debugging, server

Sorry if this is a simple question I'm pretty new to this. I'm trying to use the flask debug toolbar extension and it's raising an import error and I'm not entirely sure why.

Here is a screenshot of everything that's happening with the exact text blocks below:

**Screenshot:** https://gyazo.com/1b8d0bf5eb4795b68e03a48395180ea1

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__) 

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "iliketurtles"
debug = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

@app.route ('/')
def say_hello():
    return render_template("hello.html")
```

**Error:**

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/worme/OneDrive/Desktop/School Work/Worksheets/Unit 25/25.2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/worme/OneDrive/Desktop/School Work/Worksheets/Unit 25/25.2/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
  File "/mnt/c/Users/worme/OneDrive/Desktop/School Work/Worksheets/Unit 25/25.2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask.globals import _request_ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask.globals' (/mnt/c/Users/worme/OneDrive/Desktop/School Work/Worksheets/Unit 25/25.2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/globals.py)
```

*I tried downgrading and upgrading flask as well as the debug toolbar but to no avail.*

Comment: seems this is [known issue](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-debugtoolbar/issues/213)